# Why do I need static_cast and std::remove_reference in std::move if I pass an rvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmove

I'm trying to understand more move semantic. Now this is a possible implementation of `std::move`:

```
template <typename T>
typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& move_(T&& obj)
{
    return static_cast<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&&>(obj);
}
```

- But I've edited it a bit to understand its workings:

  ```
    template <typename T>
    typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& move_(T&& obj)
    {
        if(std::is_lvalue_reference<decltype(obj)>::value)
            return static_cast<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&&>(obj); 
        return obj; // dones't work?
        // return (string&&)obj; // ok works
    }

    auto s = move_(std::string("Hi there!")); // passing an rvalue cause instantiating: `string&&(string&&){}`.
  ```

But why I can't directly return `obj` which is of `rvalue-reference type` after instantiation?

Comment: `std::move()` *accepts* lvalue and rvalue references as input (because the parameter is a *universal reference*), but **inside** of `std::move()` the parameter is treated as an lvalue reference (because it has a name), hence why the cast is needed to convert it into an rvalue reference on return.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ok thanks get it now.

Comment: @RemyLebeau you mean if i do some dirty hack to convert that lvalue into an rvalue works fine but not recommended e.g: return obj + 1; // let's assume the type parameter is an integral type?

Comment: `operator+` returns an rvalue, so it is possible to return that as an rvalue reference without using a type cast. But I wouldn’t recommend that due to lifetime issues.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ok. thanks. you can add an answer to the topic.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: In the book it is said: "The body of this function returns static_cast<string&&>(t). The type of t is already string&&, so the cast does nothing. Therefore, the result of this call is the rvalue reference it was given." So I think it is incorrect: because the cast is needed to convert that lvalue (the name of the rvalue) to an rvalue. am I correct?

Comment: yes, the cast is needed inside the function

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you so much!